# Yellow line in timeline

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, timeline, rigidbody

So I'm making an animation mixed with physics such as Rigid Body and using the particle system for effects. But when I add a collision plus a rigid body, this yellow line in the timeline appears. As I replay my animation, it looked weird and it's like the animation is glitching. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: When you use physics in blender. Don't make changes to your scene when the cursor is in the middle of the timeline. Always go back to the first frame if you need to change anything. The yellow line means you changed something in the middle of the timeline evn though some physics have already been calculated for that frame, that's why the animation glitches.

Comment: Yes, true but then again, as I move the cursor the yellow line is still there, and it usually starts off with an orange line which calculates the physics. But this one's literally stuck on the same frame and no orange line appeared.

Comment: The orange line is there to indicate the frames that have been calculated, if you change anything in the middle, it's going to be replaced by a yellow line and it will stay there untill you resimulate again. It won't go even if you move the cursor, you have to resimulate.